# Electron video playback breaks when app is packaged

Tags: video, electron, haxe, createjs

I have created an app using Haxe, CreateJS, Electron.  It all works very nicely prior to electron packaging.  i.e.  npm start = application works fine.

Once I package the application, the app crashes when it is playing video...
i.e.  run the exe, navigate to a section that plays video, application crashes. (window goes blank white, and is unresponsive.  Devtools disconnects)

Any ideas on what could be the issue?

```
Package JSON:
{
 "name": "hvdc2",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
   "start": "electron ./bin",
   "package-win": "electron-packager ./bin --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --out=./dist --overwrite=true",
   "package-osx": "electron-packager ./bin --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --out=./dist --overwrite=true"
 },
 "author": "GE Grid Solutions",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
   "electron-packager": "^7.0.4",
   "electron-prebuilt": "^1.3.8"
 },
 "bin": {

  },
 "description": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I managed to find a workaround this issue:

My application is based like so:

`src
 dist
 node_modules
 bin`

inside of `bin` is where the source compiles to, and `dist` is where electron packages as an exectuable.

`bin/app
 bin/index.js
 bin/package.json`

where `app` holds all the real guts of the application (assets, config, index.html so forth)

Chances are that you will have a `node_modules` folder as part of your project.
Drill into that folder and find the `electron_prebuilt` folder, drill further into the `dist` folder.  Here you will find a copy of the core files you need for executing your application.

you will notice that the files here look very much like the files that are generated by the packager in your root dist folder.  When you run the `electron.exe` file in this folder, it will tell you that you need to provide an application.  Copy your `app` folder into the resources folder here, and run the `electron.exe` file.  You will notice that your application runs perfectly.

So just use the files here as your application.

Comment: There is a downfall to this workaround.  It seems to work for Windows 64 bit environments, but fails for windows 32 bit environments.